# Parse any days on string in php

Tags: php

Can i parse any of these strings in array with `explode()` ?

The array look like this

```
$array = [
   'North AmericaWed 20:00',
   'North AmericaWed 20:00',
   'New ZealandTue 14:00',
   'IndonesiaThu 08:00'
];
```

I want to get country name without days attached to it.

This is the `php` code I thought of:

```
foreach($array as $string){
   $parse = explode('any days' , $string);
   $result = $parse[0];
}

and the result is :

North America
New Zealand
Indonesia
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: try to parse the string using regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = [
   'North AmericaWed 20:00',
   'North AmericaWed 20:00',
   'New ZealandTue 14:00',
   'IndonesiaThu 08:00'
];  

foreach($array as $string){
   $country = preg_replace('/[0-9]*:[0-9]*+/', '', $string);
   echo substr($country,0,-4).'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: ahh, thank you very much , i did not think regex can solved it in early , once more thank you very much man

Answer (score 1):

Its very odd to code but, If you really need this,here is the way

```
    <?php
$array = [
   'North AmericaWed 20:00',
   'North AmericaWed 20:00',
   'New ZealandTue 14:00',
   'IndonesiaThu 08:00'
];
$countries = array(); 
foreach($array as $string){
   //$parse = explode('Wed ' , $string);
   $parse = preg_split('/Mon |Tue |Wed |Thu |Fri |Sat |Sun /',$string);
   $countries[] = $parse[0]."\n";
}
$countries = array_unique($countries);
print_r($countries);
?>
```

Check demo : https://eval.in/620874

Output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => North America

    [2] => New Zealand

    [3] => Indonesia

)
```

I suggest change your code from where you are creating above string(`country+day and time`)